# lapply to data.frame

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I have a data.frame `DF` with the following structure:

```
ID       date CDS4 
1 ARGENT CDS USD SR  2000-01-31 4 
2 ARGENT CDS USD SR  2000-02-29 9.2
```

I would like to use the values in the columns of the data frame as parameters for a function. Something along these lines:

```
override_fields <- c("SW_SPREAD","SW EFF DT")
overrides <- c(DF$CDS5,DF$date)

d <- bdp(override_fields, overrides)
```

Is there a way to apply the `bdp` function here across all of the rows in the data frame? Perhaps using `lapply`?

Comment: What is `bdp`? If it's not already vectorized, you could use an implicit loop by `Vectorize()`-ing `bdp`.

Comment: sorry - bdp is a function in the Rbbg package. Not sure how to  vectorize() it

Comment: Take a look at `? Vectorize`. All it does is build an `mapply` call based on your function. Not necessarily efficient, but it will do what you want, I believe.

Comment: It really depends on what parameters the `bdp` function takes and how it like them. Does it take exactly two parameters? And must they be vectors or length 1?